# difficult to understand two parameters in the plt.subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I cannot understand two paramaters in the `plt.subplots(2,1, figsize=(10,8))`.
Is 2 for two plots? and what about 1?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
letter_prop = subtable / subtable.sum().astype(float)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,1, figsize=(10,8))
letter_prop['M'].plot(kind = 'bar', rot = 0 , ax=axes[0], title="Male")
letter_prop['F'].plot(kind = 'bar', rot = 0 , ax=axes[1], title="Female", legend = False)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried reading the docs? http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=subplots#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots), the signature of the function is 
`matplotlib.pyplot.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, sharex=False, sharey=False, squeeze=True, subplot_kw=None, gridspec_kw=None, **fig_kw)`

Where the two first parameters are the number of rows and columns of the grid.